Jetpack Compose: Internal class state change
I'm making a small game on Jetpack Compose (don't ask why). I have a class Health which is responsible for health. Here is its implementation:
class Health(private var maxHealth: Long) {
    private var _currentHealth = maxHealth
    val currentHealth: Long get() = _currentHealth
    val currentMaxHealth: Long get() = maxHealth

    fun applyAction(hp: Long, action: Action): Long {
        when (action) {
            Action.HURT -> _currentHealth -= hp
            Action.HEAL -> _currentHealth = max(maxHealth, _currentHealth + hp)
            Action.INCREASE_MAX_HP -> maxHealth += hp
        }
        return currentHealth
    }

    fun hurtBy(hp: Long): Long {
        return applyAction(hp, Action.HURT)
    }

    fun healBy(hp: Long): Long {
        return applyAction(hp, Action.HEAL)
    }

    fun increaseMaxHpBy(hp: Long): Long {
        return applyAction(hp, Action.INCREASE_MAX_HP)
    }

    enum class Action {
        HURT,
        HEAL,
        INCREASE_MAX_HP
    }
}

As you can see it has healBy and hurtBy methods. When I try to use them, the state of the enemy does not update.
//ViewModel Class
private val _state = MutableStateFlow(Storage())
val state = _state.asStateFlow()

private val data get() = _state.value

fun attack() {
    var damageToEnemy = data.player.weapon.damage.rollDamage()
    if (data.enemy is MarcusKnight) {
        damageToEnemy -=
            if ((data.enemy as MarcusKnight).defending) (data.enemy.currentArmor * 1.5).toLong()
            else data.enemy.currentArmor
    }
    damageToEnemy = max(damageToEnemy, 0)
    data.enemy.currentHealth.hurtBy(damageToEnemy) //<--here is the problem
    updateBattleText("You attacking by $damageToEnemy damage")
    nextTurn()
}

data class Storage(
    val state: State = State.EXPLORING,
    val currentLocation: Location = Garden(),
    val player: Player = Player(),
    val currentText: String = "",
    val enemy: Enemy = MarcusKnight(),
    val playersTurn: Boolean = true
)

Debug shows that internal state of health class is updated, but when function ends the health restores (or event did not change at all).
The Enemy class is interface for a fact:
interface Enemy {
    val name: String
    val currentWeapon: Weapon
    val currentHealth: Health
    val currentArmor: Long
    val inventory: MutableList<Item>
    fun rollTurn(): EnemyTurn
    fun defend()
    fun claim(): Enemy

    enum class EnemyTurn {
        ATTACK,
        DEFEND,
        NONE,
        USE_ITEM
    }
}

MarcusKnight is just realisation. So, the main question is how do I update health? The state of internal classes not appending? Why?
Here is what I tried:
_state.update { it.copy(enemy = data.enemy.apply { currentHealth.hurtBy(damageToEnemy) }) }

But still no result.
P.S. After testing I discovered that enemy CAN hurt:
Enemy.EnemyTurn.ATTACK -> {
    val playerArmor =
         if (data.player.isDefending)
            (data.player.armor * 1.5).toLong()
         else
            data.player.armor
    val damage = data.enemy.currentWeapon.damage.rollDamage() - playerArmor
    data.player.health.hurtBy(damage) //health changed
    updateBattleText("${data.enemy.name} attacks you by $damage")
}

class Player {
    var isDefending = false
    var weapon: Weapon = HeroSword()
    val health: Health = Health(5000)
    val armor: Long = 100
    private val inventory = mutableListOf<Item>()
    val playerInventory get() = inventory

    fun addItem(item: Item) {
        inventory.add(item)
    }

    fun useItem(item: Item): ConsumableEffect? {
        if (item !is Consumable) return null
        return if (inventory.remove(item))
            item.consume()
        else
            null
    }

    fun dropItem(item: Item) {
        inventory.remove(item)
    }

    fun defend() {isDefending = true}
    fun stopDefending() { isDefending = false}
}


Edit: I also tried to change enemy like this:
abstract class Enemy {
    abstract val name: String
    abstract val currentWeapon: Weapon
    val currentHealth: Health = Health(10000) // <-- Working as intended
//    abstract val currentHealth: Health      // <-- Not working
    abstract val currentArmor: Long
    abstract val inventory: MutableList<Item>
    abstract fun rollTurn(): EnemyTurn
    (...)
}


------------------------ Here is intended work (as player being attacked) ------------------------

But I believe it's not the right way to do it

You seem to just mutate the content of the StateFlow, you do not set a different value. The StateFlow cannot detect that and therefore it cannot notify the collectors of the new value. That means the your composables will still have the updated value, but no recomposition is triggered and the UI isn't updated. The solution is to use only immutable types in the StateFlow.

You wrong, because player health changes and updates in UI. So, I tried to make Enemy as abstract class - nothing. But when I make health of the enemy not abstract (made default value) - it worked. So how does this work then?

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you reduce your code to a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue?

Added some info

I can not point the issue directly but it is clear that recomposition is not happening. To be sure, You can add SideEffect { Log.v("TAG", "recomposition")} just to be sure. And I think it is happening because of the following code block enemy = data.enemy.apply { currentHealth.hurtBy(damageToEnemy) }). Because you are returning the instance of enemy with apply. So, compose does not understand if your data has changed

The case is not about recomposition, everything happens in ViewModel. And apply doesn't work either, I tried it (look in question). The main thing about question: when I use health in class - everything works. When in abstract class or interface, changes dont apply
